# How much swap when striping accross two disks and hibernating

Tags: boot, partitioning, raid, swap, hibernate

When a computer has two hard drives it might make sense to have two swap partitions, one on each disk - thus the swap is automatically stripped and thus much faster than otherwise.

When configuring a system for hibernation, the swap is said to need roughly 1.5x the size of the RAM, so that it is able to hold a snapshot of the RAM at the time when the system is hibernated.

What does this mean when the swap is striped across two volumes? Do the swap partitions need to be each 1.5x the RAM size, or is the snapshot only stored of one of the partitions, thus requiring at least one of them to be 1.5x the ram size?

In this last case, can size of the two partitions be different and the data still striped? If so, given a 1.5 x RAM_size partition how big should the other be?

Comment: 1. the Ubuntu version is irrelevant to this question. 2. Multiple swaps are always automatically striped.

Comment: I am not using an EOL version.

Comment: And I have retracted, but I am also done helping you.  That is my opinion because you feel it is not important.